# Display partial dynamic content once it is built and appended to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am supporting a website. On one of the pages, the site uses ajax to retrieve data from the backend and, after receiving data, build charts (i.e. pie and bar charts) one by one and append each chart to the page. The 3rd party chart tool is Highcharts. Here is the code structure:

HTML:

```
<div id="charts"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: backend_URL
    dataType: json,
    success: function(data) {
      var container = $('#charts');
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
         var chart = ...build-a-chart-by-using-data-item-and-Highcharts...;
         container.append(chart);
      }
    }
});
```

The problem with this code is that the page doesn't display anything until all charts are built and appended. If there are 100 charts, then it is a quite long wait for a user. The better user experience should be building a chart and showing it to the user so that the user can see the progress and look at what is displayed (instead of seeing a blank screen or a modal spinning wheel). How can I do it the better way? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you create one container and load data into it, which is possibly why it doesn't work smoothly.

You are loading large amounts of data at once. Instead, you could try creating separate divs for each chart.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/59ucxq1a/

```js
Highcharts.ajax({
  url: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/activity.json',
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(data) {

    data = JSON.parse(data);
    data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {

        var chartDiv = document.createElement('div');
      chartDiv.className = 'chart';
      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(chartDiv);

      Highcharts.chart(chartDiv, {
        title: {
          text: dataset.name,
        },
        series: [{
          data: dataset.data,
          name: dataset.name,
          type: dataset.type,
        }]
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.chart {
    height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing the idea. I will give it a try and report back

Comment: My actual code is quite complex and everything is based on JQuery. It seems impossible to modify and make it work your way. I created a JQuery example to mimic your code structure to see if it is working, but somehow it is not working. Here is the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hwaj9154/1/ Do you know why it is not working? The version of Highcharts I use is 4.2.3.

Comment: It's something with the jQuery configuration, Highcharts can't find it in the DOM tree, as it says error in console. Solution with JavaScript should also work in the environment when possible is use jQuery. Regarding the version of Highcharts it looks like a good solution would be to upgrade to a higher version, for the 4.2.3 you specified this solution does not work. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ev1mtjga/)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I can't fix the issue I have your way at this moment, but I trust your solution.